# Flutter unit test failed

Tags: unit-testing, dart, flutter

I was trying to do a unit test in Flutter.

In `pubspec.yaml` the dependency is included:

`test: any`

Running `flutter analyze` shows no warnings.

Created a `unit_test.dart` under `test` folder in my project:

```
import 'package:test/test.dart';

void main()
{
    test('this is a test', (){
        expect(42, equals(42));
        //expect(42,42);
    });
}
```

Running `flutter test` shows me the following error:

```
➜  HelloFlutter flutter test test/unit_test.dart
00:00 +0: loading /home/tr/programs/HelloFlutter/test/unit_test.dart            00:00 +0 -1: loading /home/tr/programs/HelloFlutter/test/unit_test.dart         00:00 +0 -1: loading /home/tr/programs/HelloFlutter/test/unit_test.dart                            
  Failed to load "/home/tr/programs/HelloFlutter/test/unit_test.dart": Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null
  package:test              test
  test/unit_test.dart 6:2   main
  dart:async                _StreamController.add
  websocket_impl.dart 1111  _WebSocketImpl._WebSocketImpl._fromSocket.<fn>
  dart:async                _EventSinkWrapper.add
  websocket_impl.dart 333   _WebSocketProtocolTransformer._messageFrameEnd
  websocket_impl.dart 228   _WebSocketProtocolTransformer.add

00:00 +0 -1: Some tests failed.
```

Any hint?

Comment: Just tried it and get exactly the same result. I haven't yet tried tests with Flutter before myself.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7154

Answer (score 1):

The actual test you posted looks like a regular "test" test, as opposed to a "flutter_test" test. So you probably just want to run it using regular dart rather than via flutter's test harness.

The diagnostics we give in these situations are horrific. That's being tracked at: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6187

Comment: Oh man, that explains why I keep seeing people do `expects(42, 42)` !

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following dependency to use `flutter test` :

```yaml
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Comment: Tried the above method, when running `flutter packages get`, it gets these errors: `Incompatible dependencies on flutter... pub get failed`

Comment: It works on my project. Could you post your pubspec.yaml ?

Comment: I also tried it in my flutter project and this fixed it for me.

Comment: The `pubspec.yaml` is the default one created by `flutter create`. Added the lines above per Alex's input only.

Comment: Really strange because I did `flutter create`, created a file `test/my_test.dart` with your test content and ran `flutter test` to see the same error you faced. After putting only the dependency mention in my answer the error went away and the test was run.

Comment: Let me try later today and revert.

Comment: Tried again today and seems working with Alex's method.